# Inequality between coefficients of a polynomial and its supremum

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, polynomials

For $d, m \in\mathbb{N}$ fixed, let $P\equiv P(x) := \sum_{|\alpha|\leq m} c_\alpha\cdot x^\alpha$ be a real polynomial in $d$ variables of (total) degree $m$. (That is, the above sum ranges over all multiindices $\alpha=(i_1, \ldots, i_d)\in\mathbb{N}_0^{\times d}$ of length $|\alpha|\equiv i_1+\ldots + i_d$ less than $m$.)

Is it possible to estimate the maximum coefficient $\|c_\alpha\|_\infty := \max_{|\alpha|\leq m}|c_\alpha|$ of $P$ against its uniform norm $\|P\|_{\infty;K}:= \sup_{x\in K}|P(x)|$, for  $K$ some compact set in $\mathbb{R}^d$?

That is, does there exist a compact set $K$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ together with a constant $\kappa \equiv \kappa(m,d,K)>0$ such that

$$\tag{1}\|c_\alpha\|_\infty \ \leq \ \kappa\cdot \|P\|_{\infty; K} \qquad \text{ for each } \ P \ \text{ as above}?$$

Any references are welcome.

**Edit:** Do you know if $\kappa$ can be chosen independent of $m$, or at least such that the sequence $(\kappa(m,d,K))_{m\geq 0}$ is bounded (for $K$ and $d$ fixed)?

Comment: is it okay if $K$ depends on $m$ and $d$?

Comment: $K$ is allowed to depend on $d$, but should not depend on $m$.

Comment: Any two norms on a finite-dimensional space are equivalent.

Comment: Hi rmceraf and welcome to the MathOverflow: though it is not forbidden to [cross post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4335414/estimate-the-coefficients-of-a-polynomial-against-its-maximum) across the site and the Mathematics Stack Exchange, **1.** At least a week should have passed between the two post, and **2.** It should be stated in the body of the question. These requirements are just to let all users the possibility to answer and avoid cluttering the two web sites.

Comment: Thanks, Daniele. 

Does anyone have an idea if independence (of $\kappa$) of $m$ could also be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, such a $\kappa$ exists for every compact set $K$ with non-empty interior. Here is an abstract linear-algebra argument.

Let $V$ be the real vector space spanned by the multi-indices $\alpha$ with length at most $m$.
We have a linear map $A\colon V \to \mathbb R^K$, sending $(c_\alpha)$ to the function $x\to \sum_\alpha c_\alpha x^\alpha$. Since different polynomials cannot agree on a set with non-empty interior, this map is injective. There is then a finite subset $F\subset K$ such that the composition $V\xrightarrow A\mathbb R^K\to\mathbb R^F$ is a linear isomorphism (for example, pick the elements of $F$ one by one, making sure that the rank of the composition increases by 1 each time).

Now $\kappa$ exists by the fact that all linear isomorphisms between finite-dimensional vector spaces are bicontinuous.

If you want an explicit value for $\kappa$, you can use discrete derivatives (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference) to write $c_\alpha$ as a linear combination of some values of $P$.

Comment: This constant depends on $m$, as I ubderstood comments to OP it should not

Comment: The comment just states $K$ should not depend on $m$. But $\kappa$ can (this is clear from the notation $\kappa = \kappa(m,d,K)$.)

Comment: ah, yes, you are right

Comment: One can also use Bernstein's inequality https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein%27s_theorem_(polynomials) to get reasonable bounds, particularly in low dimensions.

Comment: Many thanks for the reference! Do you know if there is any chance that (for $d$ and $K$ fixed) the sequence $(\kappa(m,d,K))_{m\geq 0}$ will be bounded? @TerryTao

Comment: no, for example if $d=1$ and $K=[0,1]$ the Bernstein polynomials https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial are bounded on $K$ but the coefficients get large

Answer (score 1):

I've recently been looking into this problem. Here's what I've came up with to show the existence of such a $\kappa$. Let me know if there are any issues. (I gave the same answer on the [cross post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4335414/estimate-the-coefficients-of-a-polynomial-against-its-maximum/4696671#4696671))

Define the following polynomial space
$$
\mathcal{P}_{m,d,K} := 
\left\{ 
P: P(x) = \sum_{\alpha:|\alpha|\leq m} c_\alpha x^\alpha, \quad x\in K, \;c_\alpha \in \mathbb{R} \; \forall \alpha
\right\}
.
$$
It can be shown that $\mathcal{P}_{m,d,K}$ is a [vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space).
Further, since every $P\in\mathcal{P}_{m,d,K}$ can be represented as a linear combination of finitely many basis functions ($x^\alpha$), then $\mathcal{P}_{m,d,K}$ is a finite dimensional vector space.

Then we have the following two [polynomial norms](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolynomialNorm.html), which are both valid norms on $\mathcal{P}_{m,d,K}$:
$$
\lVert 
P
\rVert_{\infty;\,K} := \sup_{x\in K}|P(x)| = \max_{x\in K}|P(x)|,
$$
and
$$
\lVert 
P
\rVert_{\infty;\,c_\alpha} := \max_{\alpha:|\alpha|\leq m}|c_\alpha| = \lVert c_\alpha \rVert_\infty.
$$
It is a well known result that all norms on finite dimensional vector spaces are equivalent ([Link1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57686/understanding-of-the-theorem-that-all-norms-are-equivalent-in-finite-dimensional), [Link2](https://math.mit.edu/%7Estevenj/18.335/norm-equivalence.pdf)).
Therefore, from the definition of [equivalent norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Equivalent_norms), there exists a $\kappa>0$ such that
$$
\lVert 
P
\rVert_{\infty;\,c_\alpha}
\leq
\kappa\lVert 
P
\rVert_{\infty;\,K}
.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer. Your approach seems correct to me.